# Terraform: will dependent resource get created if parent partially completes with error?

Tags: terraform

Note that this is a design question about possibilities for how a custom-build provider can handle error flows. Whether or not that flow is good... that's another question.

Let’s say there are 2 resources (A & B), where B depends on A.

When I run terraform apply, resource A gets created (meaning the backend created an object with an ID), but is in a bad (error) state after a creation task. What I would like to build is a provider that is able to recognize this bad state, and stop there before it goes on trying to create resource B. What I would also like, though, is a way for Terraform to be able to clean up that resource in an bad state (via destroy or taint), or even move forward without re-creating it after I fix the issue on the backend manually.

Maybe there are other flow possibilities, but here are two I can think of:

1. Since the backend gave us an ID, we set the ID in the Terraform resource also, but return from the Create method with an error. However, I'm not sure what will Terraform do next. It can either:

   A. Go on and try to create resource B since A has an ID (not desired)

   B. Refuse to try to create resource B since an error was returned from creating A (desired)

   From what I can tell, it seems like the default behavior of Terraform would be to do option A (correct me if I'm wrong). **Can I get it to do option B though?**
2. The other option is to NOT set the Terraform ID, even though there is an object on the backend now that does have an ID. The good thing is that Terraform won't move on to resource B, but that bad thing is that resource A effectively becomes an orphan; it exists on the backend, but Terraform has no way of cleaning it up.

I'm guessing this isn't a unique use case, but haven't had any luck figuring out a solution based on the docs. Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did `terraform apply` stopped with an error or did it rather create resources as told but they ended up broken? Please give an example of what you tried to do including the source code.

Comment: @jakub-kania, this doesn't have to do with any code yet. It's a design question concerning the default and possible behavior flows for Terraform (using a custom provider)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I would like to build is a provider that is able to recognize this bad state, and stop there before it goes on trying to create resource B.

This is how most (if not all) providers maintained by HashiCorp, vendors and the community work.

The existence (or lack of) resource ID does not make any difference in error handling.

It is a convention for a resource to have an ID even if it's in pending/failure state. Resource code should always be setting ID as soon as it's possible (typically right after 1st successful response from the API, **before** any retry logic). A resource practically lives and dies with its ID. Removal of its ID means removal of the resource from state and should only occur if the resource is *actually* gone (e.g. API returns 404).

Terraform will always try to get as far as it can during any `apply` or `destroy` operation. It will walk through a graph of all resources in your config and if an error occurs (i.e. is returned from the C/R/U/D method) it will keep creating/updating/destroying only those resources **which are unaffected** by the error - basically all resources which don't depend on the failed resource. You can inspect the full dependency graph on which Terraform's making decisions via `terraform graph`.

For example if you have `aws_s3_bucket_object` depending (either via interpolation syntax or via `depends_on`) on `aws_s3_bucket` and creation/update/destruction of the `aws_s3_bucket` fails for any reason then `aws_s3_bucket_object` will remain untouched.

[image]

> What I would also like, though, is a way for Terraform to be able to clean up that resource in an bad state (via destroy or taint), or even move forward without re-creating it after I fix the issue on the backend manually.

It is more or less a design choice **not** to perform any automated rollbacks (like destroying resources in "failed" state) in case of failures. There's a number of ways any operation can fail and opinions of what's the best rollback strategy differ based on context, so Terraform intentionally leaves this to an operator/user.

Tainting however is a different story, because it doesn't directly affect the resource and still leaves the final decision on the user.

There is *currently* no way to automatically `taint` the resource from the CRUD/schema interface but there's at least [one Github issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/107) discussing this idea.

---

**Possibly Related:** Sometimes resource operation requires multiple API calls, any of which may fail. Terraform has a concept called "Partial State" to address such partial failures as described in https://www.terraform.io/docs/plugins/provider.html#resource-data

Basically it always makes sure that even a partial state is stored before returning the error.